# TF - normalize and visualize heatmaps on Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-slim

I have a network which should take as input a batch of 10 images of size 100x100 and produce 21 heatmaps for each image. Thus the output is a tensor (10, 100, 100, 21).

The problem is that I want to visualise this output (e.g. for tensorboard) and each 100x100 heatmap needs normalising. Things would be straightforward if the output had only one heatmap per image.

What is an efficient way to implement the above?